# Share variables between Fragment (UI) and Surfaceview Threads(Android)

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments, surfaceview

I am loading a layout with a surfaceview to a fragment. The layout has buttons which would change the behavior of surfaceview. Surface view is working with a event queue which is processed by the thread. I want to share variables safely between UI thread (fragment) and surfaceview processing thread. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. Why are you trying to share variables? Maybe you should think your design in terms of tasks to be performed, not in terms of variables. This may lead to a cleaner design as multithreading code easily gets out of control. Nevertheless, you can always share variables by properly guarding them (that is synchronizing access to it). On certain occasions, you would not even need to guard it if the access to that variable is sequential (thread access never overlaps with each other).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Whats drawn on surfaceview is generated by a background thread. UI thread has some buttons which executes some logic using the variables used by surfaceview thread. I want to lock these variables properly to avoid concurrency issues.